Maple equation problem : Limit and Sum at the same time
I need to evaluate

using the Maple Software.
I did manage to make my equation look like the given by using
"Limit(Sum(1/(i^(9/5)), i=1..n),i = infinity);"
However, I could not proceed any further as I tried using evalf for result but nothing returned even if I switched the uppercase L and S for limit and sum.

Your code is taking,
Limit(..., i = infinity)
but that's a typo. It ought to be,
Limit(..., n = infinity)
limit(sum(1/k^(9/5),k=1..n), n=infinity);

     Zeta(9/5)

evalf(%);

     1.882229618

You could also do that as,
Limit(Sum(1/i^(9/5), i = 1 .. n), n=infinity);
value(%);
evalf(%);

